# How to Get Valid Json if Using Multiple foreach Loops

Tags: php, json, magento, soap

```
$base = 'http://Yourhost';
$proxy = new SoapClient($base.'/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
if ($sessionId = $proxy - > login('user123', 'user123')) {
    echo "LoginSuccess";
}
$allCategories = $proxy - > catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, 2);
$allCategories = get_object_vars($allCategories);
foreach($allCategories['children'] as $k = > $v {
        $v = get_object_vars($v);
        echo $cat[] = json_encode(array("Category" = > $v['name']));
        // echo 'Category id and name->'.$v['category_id'].$v['name']."</br>";
        $subCat = $proxy - > catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, $v['category_id']);
        $subCat = get_object_vars($subCat);
        foreach($subCat['children'] as $k1 = > $v1) {
            $v1 = get_object_vars($v1);
            echo $subcat1 = json_encode(array("SubCategory" = > $v1['name']));
            //echo $subcat1.",";
            //echo 'SubCategory Id and Name ->'.$v1['category_id'].$v1['name']."</br>";
            $res = $proxy - > catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId, $v1['category_id']);
            // echo json_encode($res);
            //$res=get_object_vars($res);
            //$subcat1[]=$v1['category_id'].$v1['name'];
            foreach($res as $key = > $value) {
                // echo "product"."</br>";
                $value = get_object_vars($value);
                echo $pdt[] = json_encode(array("Product_ID" = > $value['product_id']));
                //$pdt[]=$value['product_id'];
                // echo 'Product ID ->'.$value['product_id']."</br>";
            }
        }
        //echo json_encode(array("ProductDemo"=>$res));
    }
```

I am Getting Output Like this-

```
{
    "Category": "Mens Wear"
}{
    "Category": "Womens Wear"
}{
    "Category": "Mobile Phones"
}{
    "Category": "Grocery"
}{
    "SubCategory": "SPICES & SEASONING"
}{
    "SubCategory": "CEREALS & PULSES"
}{
    "SubCategory": "RICE & FLOUR"
}{
    "Product_ID": 13
}{
    "Product_ID": 24
}{
    "SubCategory": "OIL & GHEE"
}{
    "SubCategory": "SWEETNER & WHITNER"
}{
    "SubCategory": "OTHERS"
}{
    "Category": "Food"
}{
    "SubCategory": "DRIED READY MEALS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "SAUCES,SPREADS & PICKLES"
}{
    "SubCategory": "BAKERY"
}{
    "SubCategory": "CHIPS & NAMKEENS"
}{
    "Category": "BEVERAGES"
}{
    "SubCategory": "TEA & COFFEE"
}{
    "SubCategory": "HEALTH & ENERGY DRINKS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "FRUIT DRINKS"
}{
    "Category": "PERSONAL CARE"
}{
    "SubCategory": "FACE CARE & LOTION"
}{
    "SubCategory": "FACE WASH & SCRUBS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "SHAMPOO & CONDITIONER"
}{
    "Product_ID": 17
}{
    "SubCategory": "ORAL CARE"
}{
    "SubCategory": "BODY & HANDWASH"
}{
    "SubCategory": "HAIR OIL & SERUM"
}{
    "Product_ID": 16
}{
    "Product_ID": 21
}{
    "SubCategory": "DEO,PERFUMES & TALC"
}{
    "SubCategory": "HAIR STYLING CREAMS & GEL"
}{
    "SubCategory": "SHAVING NEEDS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "SHOE CARE"
}{
    "Category": "DETERGENT & TOILETRIES"
}{
    "SubCategory": "DETERGENT BAR & POWDER"
}{
    "Product_ID": 14
}{
    "Product_ID": 15
}{
    "Product_ID": 20
}{
    "Product_ID": 22
}{
    "SubCategory": "SANITARY&FLOOR CLEANERS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "FABRIC CARE"
}{
    "SubCategory": "DETERGENT BAR & POWDER"
}{
    "SubCategory": "DISHWASHER AGENTS"
}{
    "Category": "Baby CARE"
}{
    "SubCategory": "BABY DIAPERS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "BABY CREAMS"
}{
    "Product_ID": 18
}{
    "SubCategory": "BABY SOAP"
}{
    "SubCategory": "BABY SHAMPOO"
}{
    "SubCategory": "BABY OIL"
}{
    "SubCategory": "BABY FOOD"
}{
    "Category": "OTHER PRODUCTS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "REPELLENT"
}{
    "SubCategory": "MEDICATIONS&TREATMENT"
}{
    "Product_ID": 23
}{
    "SubCategory": "WOMEN'S HYGIENE"
}{
    "SubCategory": "CONDOMS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "SEXUAL WELLNESS"
}{
    "SubCategory": "FOIL PAPER & NAPKINS"
}
```

That is not a valid json format.
I am doing like this because i need it in same tree format like `Category->SubCategory->Products`.

Comment: Please show us an example of the correctly serialized data.
You shouldn't use multiple serializations to reorganize your data. First create an object or array containing reorganized data that can be then json_encoded.

Comment: That is the main problem... I have to combine all three array with their position.All i have done in the script just needed valid json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need formating array in php like this

```
$result = array(
   'category data' => 'data etc'
   'subcategory' => array(
      'subcategory_data' => array();
   )
);
```

and you need call `json_encode($result)` after generate this array.

```
$allCategories = $proxy - > catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, 2);
$allCategories = get_object_vars($allCategories);
$i = 0;
foreach($allCategories['children'] as $k = > $v {
        $v = get_object_vars($v);
        $cat[$i] = array("Category" => $v['name']);
        $subCat = $proxy - > catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, $v['category_id']);
        $subCat = get_object_vars($subCat);
        $ii = 0;
        foreach($subCat['children'] as $k1 = > $v1) {
            $v1 = get_object_vars($v1);
            echo $cat[$i]["SubCategory"][$ii]['nameCategory'] = > array($v1['name']);
            $res = $proxy - > catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId, $v1['category_id']);

            $iii = 0;
            foreach($res as $key = > $value) {
                $value = get_object_vars($value);
                 $cat[$i]["SubCategory"][$ii]['product_ids'][$iii] => $value['product_id'];
                $iii++;
            }
            $ii++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
echo json_encode($cat);
```

but this bad example you need self try generate array and echo by `json_encode()` this array once.